# How to enable GPU in docker with Nginx

Tags: docker, tensorflow

My flask app uses TensorFlow GPU so in the background GPU is needed when running the app in a docker container.

If I only use the flask docker container with the bellow command, it works perfectly with GPU.

```
sudo docker run -it --gpus all -p 8080:8080 MyFlaskApp:latest
```

But when using uwsgi and nginx the I had to use a docker-compose file as below:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  gpu:
    image: nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-base-ubuntu20.04
    command: nvidia-smi
    runtime: nvidia

  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=MyFlaskApp
    expose:
      - 8080

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

But this docker-compose is not using the GPU. That's why the whole app throwing error. How can I enable GPU here?

Comment: Have you installed CUDA Driver on host OS?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera yes! As I can run it by using "sudo docker run -it --gpus all -p 8080:8080 MyFlaskApp:latest" command (GPU is running this time).

Comment: You didn't add the GPU to the `flask` service in your `docker-compose`. Check [the docs on enabling GPU access with compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/). Particularly, check the thing at the very bottom ("access specific devices") to see how to add the GPU to a specific service.

Answer (score 0):

Try running with the command

```
docker run -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow \
   python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))
```

as shown in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker)